# For any random variable X, the propability that X>E(X) is 1/2?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

From what I understand, the random variable is a function from output to integer, so I do not understand why a function can be used to compare with a number, can someone help me with this question?

Comment: We call it 'median'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim in the title is not true.  For a counterexample, let $X$ be a Bernoulli random variable with success probability $p$, where $p \in[0,1) \setminus\{1/2\}$.  Then $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0(1-p)+1p = p$, and $$\mathbb{P}(X>\mathbb{E}(X)) = \mathbb{P}(X>p) = \mathbb{P}(X=1) = p \not= 1/2.$$